# how to start SQL Server 2008 service from command prompt?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i want to start the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 services from command prompt.
how can i achieve through command prompt?

Comment: This almost definitely belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180965.aspx)

On top of that here is how you can [Manage SQL Server Services from the Command Line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd421654.aspx) which may be more relevant to what you are after.